# CF/SQL & QofQ - How to join records

Tags: sql, coldfusion

In Coldfusion, I have two datasources: dwq and prq. I'm querying dwq for a news_id that will be compared against the pageid in prq.

```
<cfquery name="dwq" datasource="cu_dsn">
 SELECT  NEWS_ID 
 FROM  dw 
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="prq" datasource="commonspot">
 SELECT 
     PAGEID, 
        TITLE
 FROM pr
 WHERE (PUBLISH ='Yes' OR PUBLISH=NULL)
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="join" dbtype="query">
 SELECT
        prq.PAGEID, 
        prq.TITLE
     dwq.NEWS_ID
 FROM prq, dwq
 where prq.pageid <> dwq.news_id
</cfquery>
```

What I need to do is select all records in the prq datasource that do not match a news_id. Since I cannot use JOIN in QofQ, I was hoping to substitute a WHERE clauses, but the SQL is returning one record multiple times (equal to the # of records in dwq).

Could someone please assist with the proper SQL to use? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If the two tables dw and pr are both available via the same datasource (your question suggests they are not) then Spiny Norman's first approach is the way to go.

If not, you could do something similar by replacing your second query (prq) with:

```
<cfquery name="prq" datasource="commonspot">
 SELECT 
     PAGEID, 
     TITLE
 FROM pr
 WHERE (PUBLISH ='Yes' OR PUBLISH=NULL)
     AND PAGEID NOT IN (#valuelist(dwq.news_id)#)
</cfquery>
```

You wouldn't then need your third query (join).  Not sure how well this would perform with large numbers of rows in dw though, and your DBMS may have a limit on the number of IDs it will accept in an IN.

Comment: Thanks Tim! This does work just like I wanted. Alas, there will be an ever growing list of records in dw; however, there will be quite a few NULL values that I have filtered out (WHERE news_id IS NOT NULL). Thank you so much!

Comment: You can do an INNER join using ColdFusion Query of Queries, using the `FROM variableName1, variableName2 WHERE variableName1.x = variableName2.x` syntax (you can NOT use INNER JOIN ... ON syntax); However, to vote for the addition of OUTER JOIN syntax (among other improvements to QoQ) vote for this Bug/ER: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=71968

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't really know anything about CF or QofQ, but in regular SQL, to get all records from prq that do not match a certain news_id you would use:

```
SELECT
    prq.PAGEID,
    prq.TITLE
FROM prq
WHERE prq.pageid <> {dwq.news_id} -- That is, insert the proper news_id here in the correct coldfusiony way
```

If you want to get all prq's that don't match any dwq.news_id (all pages that are not news pages, I guess), use:

```
SELECT
    prq.PAGEID,
    prq.TITLE
FROM prq
WHERE prq.pageid NOT IN (
    SELECT NEWS_ID
    FROM dwq
)
```

HTH, And good luck. Maybe I'll try to find out how to do this in CF later. Be sure to post back when you find out how to get it to work!

EDIT: Ah, here we go: if you want to loop over the news_ids in query 1 and get all pageids that are not that news id (maybe for a list of links to other items?), use:

```
<cfloop query="dwq">
    <cfquery name="prq" datasource="commonspot">
        SELECT 
            PAGEID, 
            TITLE
         FROM pr
         WHERE (PUBLISH ='Yes' OR PUBLISH=NULL)
           AND PAGEID <> #dwq.NEWS_ID#
    </cfquery>

    <cfdosomethingwithquery query="prq">
        ...
    </cfdosomethingwithquery>
</cfloop>
```

I think. This would probably use a lot more queries than necessary, though.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately CF QofQ doesn't allow for joins/except/not in. And the news_id would be those listed in the first datasource, dwq.  Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well then, can't you just get all results from both datasets and do your conditional not-in-list stuff in CF instead of SQL? Anyway, I think the cavalry just arrived: @TimDawe seems to know a lot more about this stuff than I do. Good luck! ;)